# Slacko vs Precise vs Lucid Puppy Linux

Tags: puppy-linux

Puppy Linux has
[3 flavors](http://puppylinux.org/main/Download%20Latest%20Release.htm)
available.

I am looking for some differences between the three. This way I can make an
informed decision on which to go with, instead of randomly picking or just
getting the smallest one.

Comment: It is better to clarify for what purpose you need puppy, For example I have a old laptop which inspired by Puppy wary where as I installed puppy lucid on it before, but consumes more resource than wary. It support DEB packages, also as did lucid Puppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slacko Puppy is larger but includes Firefox

```
ISO Size: 165 MB

has the latest Firefox browser (other browsers are available through the 
Package Manager);
```

Lucid Puppy is smaller but Firefox must be downloaded

```
ISO Size: 132.6 MB

allows the user to install his/her favorite browser (user installs it from 
the Internet at first boot).
```

Answer (score 4):

**Spup (Slacko)**

`Spup` is the generic name for puppies built with Slackware binary packages. The main reason behind Spup is binary compatibility with Slackware packages, and the Puppy Package Manager can install from any of the Slackware repositories. The foremost Spup right now is "Slacko", and is currently one of our official flagship puppies.

**Upup (Lucid, Precise)**

`Upup` is the generic name for puppies built with Ubuntu packages.What you get is a very small distro (the live-CD is about 130MB) yet with just about every application you would need and the speed and ease-of-use that Puppy is famous for. All of the advantages of Puppy, plus binary compatibility with Ubuntu .deb packages -- Puppy's own Puppy Package Manager will install any packages from the vast Ubuntu repositories!

Basically a `Upup` is a Puppy that has some compatibility with Ubuntu. Typically produced using `Woof` with Ubuntu packages. Often they are named after the Ubuntu version name, for example `Lucid`, `Jaunty` and `Precise`

And between `Spup` and `Upup` it is your matter of choice. see this  [Why Slack instead of Ubuntu](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=74196&sid=90b3383257b60e3fe3a21eec63253d7e)